# Excel - gather values in adjacent columns per row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a table looking like this:

```
+------------+-------+
|    Date    | Time  |
+------------+-------+
| 14/05/2014 | 17:40 |
| 14/05/2014 | 18:18 |
| 14/05/2014 | 19:05 |
| 24/05/2014 | 08:56 |
| 24/05/2014 | 09:52 |
+------------+-------+
```

I'd like to find a way to make the values gathered in adjacent columns, like in the following example:

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    Date    | Time Value1 | Time Value2 | Time Value3 |
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 14/05/2014 | 17:40       | 18:18       | 19:05       |
| 24/05/2014 | 08:56       | 09:52       | Null        |
+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I think there's a way of doing it without using VBA, Maybe with Array function?

Thanks,

Arik

Comment: You've shown no attempt on how you have tried to  figure this out.  This is not 'give me the answer' site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your given data and based on below screenshot put following formula to `E2` cell and press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` as it is an ***array*** formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$6,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$6=$D2,ROW($B$2:$B$6)-ROW($B$1),""),COLUMN(A:A))),"Null")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

> ***Important note:*** After putting formula you have to manually apply time format as `hh:mm` or whatever you want.

[image]

Comment: Drag to right and down to fill the formula to adjacent cells.